# segmentation fault error in Opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to code a program on opencv to decide whether a human has approached ahead the camera. After I run the execution file, I get the captured video for few seconds and encounter the segmentation fault error.

The code is like this 
Here are headers:

```
#include "opencv2/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

//define static variable
static int cApp = 0;//number of approached frame
static double last = 0;

//define functions
void detectAndDisplay( Mat frame );
bool computeArea( double width, double height, double lastArea);
double runningAverage(int M);

//define opencv function and classifier
String upperbody_cascade_name = "home/pi/opencv- 3.0.0/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_upperbody.xml";
CascadeClassifier upper_cascade;
String window_name = "Capture - upper body detection";
```

Here is the main function:

```
int main( void )
{
//define variable
VideoCapture capture;
Mat frame;

//-- 1. Load the cascades
upper_cascade.load("/home/pi/opencv-3.0.0/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_upperbody.xml");

//-- 2. Read the video stream
capture.open( -1 );
if ( ! capture.isOpened() ) { printf("--(!)Error opening video capture\n"); return -1; }

while ( capture.read(frame) )
{
    if( frame.empty() )
    {
        printf(" --(!) No captured frame -- Break!");
        break;
    }
    //-- 3. Apply the classifier to the frame
    detectAndDisplay( frame );

    char c = (char)waitKey(10);
    if( c == 27 ) { break; } // escape
}

capture.release();
return 0;
}
```

Here is the `detectAndDisplay` function:

```
void detectAndDisplay( Mat frame )
{
std::vector<Rect> upperbodys;
Mat frame_gray;
cvtColor( frame, frame_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY );
equalizeHist( frame_gray, frame_gray );

//-- Detect upperbodys
upper_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, upperbodys, 1.05, 3, 0|CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );

Point center( upperbodys[0].x + upperbodys[0].width/2, upperbodys[0].y + upperbodys[0].height/2 );
ellipse( frame, center, Size( upperbodys[0].width/2, upperbodys[0].height/2 ), 0, 0, 360, Scalar( 255, 0, 255 ), 4, 8, 0 );
bool ifApproached = computeArea(upperbodys[0].width/2, upperbodys[0].height/2, last);

if (ifApproached == true) {
    cApp++;
}

if (cApp == 3) {
    cout << "have approached" << endl;
    cApp = cApp - 3;
}

//-- Show what you got
imshow( window_name, frame );
}
```

Here is the `computeArea` function:

```
bool computeArea( double width, double height, double lastArea) {
double newArea = width * height;
bool ifApproached = false;
//double presentArea = newArea;
double presentArea = runningAverage(newArea);
double DifferenceBewteenAreas = presentArea - lastArea;

if (DifferenceBewteenAreas > 1) {//threshold
    ifApproached = true;
}

last = presentArea;
return ifApproached;
}
```

Here is `runningAverage` function:

```
double runningAverage(int M) {
//M is measurement
//#define LM_SIZE 5
static int LM[5];
static int index =0;
static long sum = 0;
static int count =0;

//keep sum updated to improve speed

sum = sum - LM[index];
LM[index] = M; 
sum = sum + LM[index];
index++;
index = index % 5;

if (count < 5) {
    count++;
}

return (double)(sum / (double)count);
}
```

I have searched many opencv segmentation fault questions, some said this segmentation fault was caused by wrong array used, but my case has little use of array. Others said misused of function characters could also cause this kind of errors, I agree with this, some of my characters could be wrong here.

Comment: have you tried to use a debugger to see which line caused the error? Btw. "segmentation fault" is a really generic error and just means "didn't have permission to do a specific read or write to memory"

Comment: I did not, the machine I used in the lab is one raspberry pi 3, it does not have any debuggers, and I do not  have the permission to install one. Which kind of debugger can I use in this kind of environment? I could have a try in my laptop

Comment: if you have gdb on the pi use that or use gdbserver to do remote debugging.

Comment: you can add some cout s to the code to limit the code range where the segfault occurs. e.g. at start and end of each function in the beginning.

Comment: @Micka Thanks, it is an easy way to find the bug. Actually I found that I should not use upperbodys[0] in the code, because sometimes there are no object being detected at all,so there could be some memory read error happens, I used upperbodys[i] instead.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found that I should not use upperbodys[0] in the code, because sometimes there are no object being detected at all,so there could be some memory read error happens, I used upperbodys[i] instead and it works well then.

```
void detectAndDisplay( Mat frame )
{
std::vector<Rect> upperbodys;
Mat frame_gray;
cvtColor( frame, frame_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY );
equalizeHist( frame_gray, frame_gray );

//-- Detect upperbodys

upper_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, upperbodys, 1.05, 3, 0|CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );
int size = upperbodys.size();
double newArea = -1;

for (int i = 0 ; i < size; i++) {
    Point center( upperbodys[i].x + upperbodys[i].width/2, upperbodys[i].y + upperbodys[i].height/2 );

    ellipse( frame, center, Size( upperbodys[i].width/2, upperbodys[i].height/2 ), 0, 0, 360, Scalar( 255, 0, 255 ), 4, 8, 0 );

    //bool ifApproached = computeArea(upperbodys[i].width/2, upperbodys[i].height/2, last);
    //////////////////////////////////////////


    newArea = upperbodys[i].width/2 * upperbodys[i].height/2;

    if (newArea != -1) {
        cout << "UpperBodys has value, index = " << i << endl; 
        break;
    }

}

bool ifApproached = false;
//double presentArea = runningAverage(newArea);
double presentArea = newArea;
double DifferenceBewteenAreas = presentArea - last;    

if (DifferenceBewteenAreas > 1) {//threshold
    ifApproached = true;
}

last = presentArea;
    //////////////////////////////////////////  
if (ifApproached == true) {
   cApp++;
}

if (cApp == 3) {
   cout << "have approached" << endl;
   cApp = cApp - 3;
}



//-- Show what you got
imshow( window_name, frame );
}
```